# cloning a div and applying mutliple changes in loop

Tags: jquery

I'm cloning an element on my page, in order to make changes to it in an .each() loop and then append the cloned div to the body.

I want this to be the quickest it can possibly be, so want to keep the clone outside of the loop.

my code so far is:

```
var array = [];
var result = $('#result').clone(true, true);

$.each(someOtherArray, function(i,object){

    result.find()....
    // do a bunch of stuff here, changing the clones info to that contained in the someOtherArray

    array.push(result)

 })

 $('body').append(array)
```

The only thing is, each entry in the 'array' is identical (the last object in teh .each() loop). how do I fix this?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be different? You're pushing the same `result` that has been defined outside.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep `result` outside, you're pushing the same `result` into the array over and over again. It doesn't matter if you make changes to it during each iteration; you're still pushing the same reference into the array over and over again. You will have to clone it inside the loop so that you get a *new* object each time. If you don't want the overhead of cloning and simply want to recreate the object, you can save the html that represents the element into a string, and then use that to create a new element each time.

Comment: how do i edit the content of the string easily? e.g i normally i do a .find('.some-div').text('new text'), what would I use with a string?

Comment: You would have to do `jQuery(str).find(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is change the ID of each clone do something like this :

```
var array = [];
var result = $('#result').clone(true, true);
var c = 0;

$.each(someOtherArray, function(i,object){

    result.attr('id', 'id'+(++c) );
    // here we try to change ID  

    array.push(result)

 })

 $('body').append(array)
```

Comment: inside my loop i current do: 'result.attr({ 'id':i })', which doesnt work

Comment: Use : 'result.attr('id',i)'  remove { }

Comment: This won't work. The problem is that `result` never changes; it is the same reference that's being pushed into the array.